# Confused with Console's command for manage.py

Tags: python

```py
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

when I run it into console it says:

File "manage.py", line 17
) from exc
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax .

whats the mistake in this code ? some one plss help!!

Comment: Please format your code. It is rude to ask people for help and not make an effort to present your code in a readable way.

Comment: Are you using python2? re-raising exceptions is only possible since python3 . Therefore this would cause a SyntaxError in python2.

Answer (score 0):

I copy-pasted your code in my editor and it worked fine.

I guess either you do not have the same thing on your side than what you posted here, or you have an indentation problem. Pay very close attention to indetation, or try pasting the content here back into your file.